# Eclipse GDB can't find source files

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, pydev

My workspaces are located in my home directory.

I am currently trying to debug python code which loads a shared C++ library, using Eclipse Oxygen and PyDev. I can debug the Python files just fine.

I run the program (pytest unit test if that matters) with a breakpoint somewhere in the test before the shared library is called (but after it is loaded) and then run a C/C++ Attach to Application debug and attach to the paused python thread. I then set a breakpoint in my C++ code and resume python, and get this from the GDB console output:

> No source file named /home/myname/.../models/sourcefile.cpp

Doing an `ls /home/myname/.../models` clearly shows  that that file exists.

I'm not sure if this matters but my library was compiled with CMake where the source and build directory are siblings. E.g. workspace is ~/dev and source is in ~/dev/sourceFolder and build files are in ~/dev/buildFolder

Update:

I was able to attach to the running Python debug thread manually in the console using `gdb python <thread_number>`. This works and finds my source files just fine, allowing me to debug manually in the console. It would still be much faster and less cumbersome if I were able to get it to work in Eclipse.

Things I've tried in the C++ debug config settings:

- In preferences, changing C/C++ -> Debug -> Source Lookup to have
  absolute file path first, profile first, and relative file path
  first
- In CppDebug settings debugger tab, manually added build and source directory to shared libraries
- In CppDebug settings source tab, manually added source directory in source lookup path

None of these seemed to do much.

Comment: Just guessing here, but was the library built with debug symbols enabled?

Comment: Yes, debug symbols are enabled

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, `/home/myname` probably *doesn't* exist, your `ls` only pretends that it does (but GDB doesn't).

Comment: No, I am in a dev VM running CentOS6.9

Comment: what does "/home/myname/.../" mean? Is this three dots notation an extension in your shell, possibly enabled by a configuration? My guess is, that gdb is not using the same configuration or shell. Or was that just a placeholder for regular folders you inserted in the posting?

Comment: @PaulR, it's just short notation for the full file path. There's nothing special about the path.

Answer (score 0):

For cmake projects:

The launch configuration can default to the wrong executable, so go to launch configuration => main  and check the "C/C++ Application"
Change it from this:  build/default/
to this:  build/cmake.debug.linux.x86_64/

(you can do this with the "Search Project" button.
This will then pick up the correct debug version and all your source will be found when you debug.